# Find index of the first value that is below/above a threshold

Tags: python, list, sorting, filter, find

I have a list with a series of random floats that go from negative to positive, like:

```
values = [0.001, 0.05, 0.09, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99]
```

I wish to filter out the indices that first meet the greater than/less than values that I wish. For example, if I want the first closest value less than 0.1 I would get an index of `2` and if I want the first highest value greater than 0.9 I'd get `7`.

I have a `find_nearest` method that I am using but since this dataset is randomized, this is not ideal.

EDIT: Figured out a solution.

```
low = next(x[0] for x in enumerate(list(reversed(values))) if x[1] < 0.1)
high = next(x[0] for x in enumerate(values) if x[1] > 0.9)
```

Comment: Those are not integers though?

Comment: Typo, correcting now.

Answer (score 2):

if the values list gets long you may want the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html?highlight=bisect#module-bisect)  from the standard lib

`bisect_left`, `bisect_right` may serve as the `>`, `<` tests

```
import bisect
values = [0.001, 0.05, 0.09, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99]
bisect.bisect_left(values, .1)
Out[226]: 3

bisect.bisect_right(values, .1)
Out[227]: 4
```